# Is ther a way to achieve `Shift + Home` functionality on a keyboard with Home/End keys "merged" in the numpad? (without turning it off)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, keyboard-navigation, numpad

I recently bought a laptop without noticing the <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys are "merged" with the numbers <kbd>7</kbd>/<kbd>1</kbd> on the numpad, respectively.

I know this seems a bit nit picky of me, but as a coder you can never have too many shortcuts, specially when it's one that's been taken away so, to elaborate on the title:

1. If num lock is ON
   a) <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> `--------->` Moves cursor to beginning of line
   b) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> `-->` Moves cursor to beginning of file
2. Else
   c) <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> `--------->` Selects text until beginning of line
   d) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> `-->` Selects text until beginning of file

I need (c) and (d) without having to turn <kbd>num lock</kbd> off. Does anyone know a workaround?

*Note: remember <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> are one key. Same applies to <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd>.*

Thanks

**EDIT**

Brand: Asus Vivobook 15
OS: Windows 10

Comment: That kind of depends on your laptop/keyboard manufacturer, as many have it implemented in different ways.

Comment: often Fn + [special key] is the way to toggle functionality. May depend on manufacturer.

Comment: I'd be inclined to [sharp intake of breath] … read the manual ;)

Comment: What OS are you running? Under Linux it would probably be no big deal.

Comment: Under any OS you can specify new shortcuts for such actions. Which one is it?